# mongodb DAO sets all attributes to null before save()

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I try to receive bean of a class from context, and then save it in a mongodb collection. The problem is, all of its attributes are, for unknown reasons, set to null right before saving. It works perfectly well when I try to save objects in database created by `new` operator, but not with beans:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx;
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    Komputer komputer = (Komputer)ctx.getBean("komputer");

    Dao dao = (Dao)ctx.getBean(Dao.class);
    dao.deleteAll();

    System.out.println("inserting: " + komputer.getTyp());
    dao.save(komputer); // sets everything to null and puts in db

    Komputer new_komputer = new Komputer();
    new_komputer.setTyp("test");

    System.out.println("inserting: " + komputer.getTyp());
    dao.save(new_komputer); // correctly puts in db

    Iterable <Komputer> komputer_iterable = dao.findAll();
    System.out.println("List: ");
    for (Komputer komputer : komputer_iterable) {
        System.out.println("id:" + komputer.getId() + ", typ: " + komputer.getTyp());
    }
}
```

Result printed in console:

```
inserting: Intel Pentium B970
13:33:38.719 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Inserting DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, obwodKola, liczbaLosowa] in collection: komputer
13:33:38.720 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[lab_test]
inserting: test
13:33:38.726 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Inserting DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, typ, obwodKola, liczbaLosowa] in collection: komputer
13:33:38.726 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[lab_test]
13:33:38.730 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { } fields: null for class: class org.zut.lab1.Komputer in collection: komputer
13:33:38.731 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[lab_test]
List: 
id:56657ca244ae837d313d8b29, typ: null
id:56657ca244ae837d313d8b2a, typ: test
```

Of course, all of the first objects attributes were set correctly.

This is how dao class looks like:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface Dao extends CrudRepository<Komputer, String> {

}
```

And also Komputer class:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Komputer {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Procesor procesor;
    private String typ;
    private float obwodKola; // 2 * pi * r
    private float liczbaLosowa;

    public void setProcesor(Procesor procesor) {
        this.procesor = procesor;
    }

    public Procesor getProcesor() {
        return this.procesor;
    }

    public void setTyp(String typ) {
        this.typ = typ;
    }

    public String getTyp() {
        return this.typ;
    }   

    public float getObwodKola() {
        return obwodKola;
    }

    public void setObwodKola(float obwodKola) {
        this.obwodKola = obwodKola;
    }

    public float getLiczbaLosowa() {
        return liczbaLosowa;
    }

    public void setLiczbaLosowa(float liczbaLosowa) {
        this.liczbaLosowa = liczbaLosowa;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Beans in context.xml file:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="lab_test" />
</bean>

<mongo:repositories base-package="org.zut.lab1"></mongo:repositories> 

<bean id="procesor" class="org.zut.lab1.Procesor">
    <property name="iloscRdzeni" value="4"/>
    <property name="czestotliwosc" value="300000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="komputer" class="org.zut.lab1.Komputer">
    <property name="liczbaLosowa" value="#{T(java.lang.Math).random() * procesor.czestotliwosc}"/>
    <property name="procesor" ref="procesor"/>
    <property name="obwodKola" value="#{T(java.lang.Math).PI * 2 * procesor.getIloscRdzeni()}"/>
    <property name="typ" value="Intel Pentium B970"/>
</bean>
```

This makes me totally disoriented. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the  Komputer komputer = (Komputer)ctx.getBean("komputer"); set ? are you sure Komputer has Typ set to some value  ? Just print it before you save it. Sometimes we assume and break our head. Or think about the deleteAll() actually did not delete everything,one null was left out from the database. How about you show the bean definition in context.xml ?

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper I have edited the post. All values are set correctly, they can be printed in console. Database is cleared every time I call deleteAll() method.

Comment: Please print before save to make sure

Comment: @Valijon I have added some extra debug data.

Comment: Can you visit the lab_test database and delete all the data there manually to be extra sure. if deleteAll() actually deletes all.

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper I am 100% sure the database is being cleared, just checked it. The DAO class is automatically implemented by the template specified in beans, I haven't touched it.

Comment: I believe the @@Id attribute is not being generated while creating the object through injection. That should be it. You would need to address that. You could use factory method and findout a way to generate the id while creating through injection. For test you can remove the @@Id and see if this solves.

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper when I remove @@id annotation, nothing changes. I have no idea how to create the id by injection, no tutorial which I've seen does that, but it might be the case.

Comment: @zmarszczony .May be we can find a way. But have to confirm this theory. The id maps to the object id in mongodb, having this not been generated by spring / java should have been the problem. I have another idea , remove/rename the field altogether.  And see if that solves,

Comment: "If no field named 'id' is present in the Java class then an implicit '_id' file will be generated by the driver but not mapped to a property or field of the Java class." Straight from http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper removing id attribute throws null pointer exception upon save() attempt, for both objects.

Comment: @zmarszczony refer the link http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

Comment: Typical case: I my local it works! Some changes: Can you change CrudRepository into MongoRepository? Then, instead of Dao, take MongoTemplate (MongoOperations) and try to save your values.

Comment: @Valijon First, I've tried to change CrudRepository to MongoRepository, and it didn't work. Then, I tried to use the mongoTemplate bean directly, instead of Dao, and it still didn't work. This is really problematic - I think I just should scrap the idea of beans, and create objects ,,manually''.

Comment: Upload somewhere your source code to debug, because it's really strange

Comment: By the way, can you do again and see via console your MongoDB what exactly is saved. Maybe, because of `projection`, params are set to `null`

Comment: @Valijon MongoDB receives and saves null values. Here is my project source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e94k2whc3hmu6rv/HelloWorld.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Spring AOP creates a `Proxy` for bean instance with id `komputer`.

As it proxy, it calls proxied methods (like when you mock with `Mockito`), but original attributes are null. If you debug your code with some IDE (Eclipse, for example), you can see what's happening.

So, when you save proxied instance, it takes `attribute's` value, not **getters**.

If you remove `aop proxy` from context, komputer bean will be saved correctly.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
....
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="profiler">
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* org.zut.lab1.Komputer.oblicz(..)) and args(czas)"
         id="test"/>
        <aop:around method="profile" pointcut-ref="test"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

[image: Proxy for Komputer instance]

Comment: How can I save the bean without removing the AOP part?

Comment: You can create `WritingConverter` [http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters) where you need to convert you `Komputer` into `DBObject` instance and change `mongofactory` initialization to read converter.