# Implements a Java Interface using Spring (AOP?)

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have several simple interfaces with getters and setters and a few other methods to read and write from the file system.
Using directly Java code, I could write a single "invocation handler" and use it to instantiate objects for all these interfaces (I have not tried it, but I think that it could be done).

I am wondering if it is possible to do the same using Spring.

The code below, implements a given interface. As you can easily see, the same same invocation handler, could be used for any interface.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class AOPTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler();
        AnyInterface proxy = (AnyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                                    AnyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                                    new Class[] { AnyInterface.class },
                                    handler);

        proxy.sayHello();

    }

}

interface AnyInterface {
    public void sayHello();
}

class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler{

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something similar here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133189/mongodb-dao-sets-all-attributes-to-null-before-save/34160666?noredirect=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133189/mongodb-dao-sets-all-attributes-to-null-before-save/34160666?noredirect=1)

Comment: I am sorry @Valijon, I do not see why that url should be somehow related with what I need to do.

Comment: `Interfaces` do not do any logic, just define service interface contract. So, first, you need to define interface implementation in Java code. Then, If you do not want to initiate that implementation several times, you can retrieve a `singleton` from context. In that link, there are several interfaces, like `Dao`, 'MongoOperations' where the implementation is recovered from context. Spring just helps you to initiate your classes, not define implementation syntax (how would it compile into byte-code?)

Comment: What I want to use is an invocation handler. An invocation handler can implement any interface

Comment: I have added a simple example that implements a given interface using an invocation handler. This is the basic for any proxy and proxy based AOP in java.

Comment: Normal AOP, whether done using Spring or another IOC container, *wraps* existing implementations using a proxy mechanism - rather than creating an implementation "from scratch".

Comment: @Stewart, I do not agree. First of all, not all the AOP implementations use proxies. It is true that Spring is limited to proxy implementations. I do not think that this is a problem for what I want to do. As my example shows, a proxy can create an implementation from scratch.

Comment: You have a created a proxy to execute `sayHello`, but as you see, you need to implement `somewhere` the logic. So, what do you gain by this complexy? By the way, just add new method to interface, it will print Hello!

Comment: 1) AOP = Aspect Oriented Programming = wrapping existing implementations with cross-cutting concerns. There's nothing to "not agree" about. That's what the word means. 2) Spring is not limited as to proxy implementations - it can use Javassist or CGLIB as well as built-in proxies. 3) >> I do not think that this is a problem for what I want to do.<< That's fine, but then why are you here asking about it?

Comment: @Stewart. From the Spring documentation: "It is important to grasp the fact that Spring AOP is proxy-based. See Section 10.6.1, “Understanding AOP proxies” for a thorough examination of exactly what this implementation detail actually means." and "Spring AOP is proxy-based. It is vitally important that you grasp the semantics of what that last statement actually means before you write your own aspects or use any of the Spring AOP-based aspects supplied with the Spring Framework."

Comment: @Stewart. I said that it was not a problem the fact that Spring is proxy based because proxies can implement an interface from scratch as I demonstrated in the example code. So this is my point: given that I know that with proxies I can implement an interface from scratch and that Spring uses proxies in its AOP implementation, I was expecting to find some smart way to configure an "invocation handler" with Spring.

Comment: @Valijon - I know that any other methods added to the interface will print the same message and this is exactly what I want. I want to reuse the same implementation for different methods. Why? For example, all the setters could execute a call to a remote REST service to update the property. In this case, I do not need to update a local instance because the object "lives" only in the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a clean way to do it with Spring using the ProxyFactoryBean.
In the example below this class is initialised without a target bean.
The object created does not have any target to forward requests, but it can implement any interface like any other proxy in Java.

Of course, if you try to call the proceed method on the invocation object passed to the invoke method of the MethodInterceptor, you will get a NullPointerException.

better-application-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="goodbyeMethodInterceptor" class="com.someco.GoodbyeMethodInterceptor" />

    <bean name="goodbyeProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="interfaces">
            <list>
                <value>com.someco.AnyInterface</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>goodbyeMethodInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

GoodbyeMethodInterceptor:

```
package com.someco;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class GoodbyeMethodInterceptor implements org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");

        return null;
    }

}
```

ProxyTester:

```
package com.someco;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.someco.AnyInterface;

public class ProxyTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("better-application-context.xml"); 
        AnyInterface tester = (AnyInterface) context.getBean("goodbyeProxy");
        tester.sayHello();
    }
}
```

AnyInterface:

```
package com.someco;

public interface AnyInterface {
    public void sayHello();
}
```

Basic pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.someco</groupId>
    <artifactId>proxy-tester</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>main</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration should work for you (I used your classes but I moved them in a different package just to make the code more readable).
I used the spring context to execute the same call to the factory method newProxyInstance() that you have used.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="pojoInvocationHandler" class="com.someco.PojoInvocationHandler"></bean>

    <bean id="AnyInterfaceClass" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
        <constructor-arg value="com.someco.AnyInterface"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anyInterface" class="java.lang.reflect.Proxy" factory-method="newProxyInstance">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean 
                factory-bean="AnyInterfaceClass" 
                factory-method="getClassLoader" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="AnyInterfaceClass" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="pojoInvocationHandler"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ProxyTester:

```
package com.someco;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.someco.AnyInterface;

public class ProxyTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext contex = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml"); 
        AnyInterface tester = (AnyInterface) contex.getBean("anyInterface"); 
        tester.sayHello();

        /* Implemented with the previous code */
//      callProxy();
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated
     * explanation of why function was deprecated, if possible include what 
     * should be used.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static void callProxy() {
        InvocationHandler handler = new PojoInvocationHandler();
        AnyInterface proxy = (AnyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                                    AnyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                                    new Class[] { AnyInterface.class },
                                    handler);
        proxy.sayHello();
    }

}
```

PojoInvocationHandler:

```
package com.someco;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PojoInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler{

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

        return null;
    }
}
```

AnyInterface:

```
package com.someco;

public interface AnyInterface {
    public void sayHello();
}
```

Basic pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.someco</groupId>
    <artifactId>proxy-tester</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>main</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: This looks promising even though, I was looking for a much more compact configuration.

Comment: You could implement a class with a static method that has only two parameters: "AnyInterfaceClass" and the invocation handler. This is what I am going to try for myself.

Comment: Thanks! I will not set the question as answered just to see if someone has a better solution.